# Error when creating new record of Model in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, model, associations

I have 2 models in my rails application. User and Goal.
I have set them like this:

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :goal, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Goal Model**

```
class Goal < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

Whenever I try to make a new record of the Goal model I get this error:

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

Here's my controller and view for the Goal model

**Goals Controller**

```
class GoalsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def new
        @goal = Goal.new
    end

    def create
        @goal = current_user.goal.new(goal_params)

        if @goal.save
            redirect_to @goal
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private

    def goal_params
        params.require(:goal).permit(:user_id, :goal_type)
    end
end
```

**Goals View (new action)**

```
<%= form_for(@goal) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :goal_type, "Would you like to..." %>
        <%= f.select :goal_type, ["Loose weight", "Gain weight", "Keep current weight"] %>
    </div>
    <div class="field submit">
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "button button-highlight button-block" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

In my goals table I have a column called goal_type and user_id.
I need to make it so that when creating a new record the user_id field gets automatically filled with the current_user id (using devise of course).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated the controller to `@goal = current_user.goals.new(goal_params)` and the the user model to `has_one :goal, dependent: :destroy`, but then I get this error:
`uninitialized constant User::Goals`

Comment: You can only use `.new` in that way with has many associations since you are calling it on the association. While in this case `user.goal` points to a specific attribute which can be nil.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the controller from:

```
@goal = current_user.goal.new(goal_params)
```

to:

```
@goal = current_user.build_goal(goal_params)
```

Comment: You can use .new on models like Goal.new(some_params) or with has_many relations. Consider the situation where you define a "User has_many Goals" relation. In this case you would be able to do 'current_user.goals.new'.

Comment: That what my original code. For some unknown reason it did not work.